# Workaround for ON DELETE SET DEFAULT? Better practice?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `CONSTRAINT` on a `PhotoID` column to be a REFERENCE to a FK from another table.
The `PhotoID` column in this table also has the constraint `NOT NULL`, as it should not be empty.

My **DB** does not support `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`. If I do not set `ON DELETE`, the entry from the other table cannot be deleted, but it should be. But I cannot set `ON DELETE SET NULL` either, because the column is supposed to be `NOT NULL`.

Is there a workaround? And if not, what is the better practice here, drop the `NOT NULL` constraint or the `REFERENCE` constraint?

Comment: Hi there, which MySQL version?

Comment: MySQL version = 5.7.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a foreign key on `yourtable(PhotoID)` referencing `reftable(PhotoID)`, you can use an `on delete`-trigger to simulate `on delete set default`:

```sql
create trigger trbd_rt_on_delete_set_default_1 before delete on reftable
for each row
  update yourtable set PhotoID = 1 where PhotoID = old.PhotoID;
```

The default entry `PhotoID=1` obviously has to exist in your reference table.

On the other hand, you could probably just allow `null` and treat this as the default value.